# Simplify running multiple SSH commands from a Gitlab CI runner to an external server

Tags: ssh, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Currently using the ff. (simplified) code in `.gitlab-ci.yml` to run multiple SSH commands:

```
stage: deploy
script:
  - ssh 1.2.3.4 "docker login -u foo -p bar example.com"
  - ssh 1.2.3.4 "docker pull my_image"
  - ssh 1.2.3.4 "docker run -d -p 80:80 my_image"
  - ssh 1.2.3.4 "and so on ..."
  - ssh 1.2.3.4 "exit"
```

It works but is there a simpler way to do this, for e.g., without specifying `ssh 1.2.3.4` in every line?

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables and make them [protected](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#protected-cicd-variables) passing from the GitLab project level configuration

In order to minimalize duplication please use [!reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#reference-tags) like this:

```yaml
.ssh-access:
  script:
    - ssh 1.2.3.4

script:
 - !reference [.ssh-access, script]
 - docker login
 - ...
```

But you can't add this to the very same line, or you can try, I haven't checked

You can try multiline commands as well:

```yaml
script:
 - |
   !reference [.ssh-access, script]
   docker login
   ...
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure how is it going minimize repetitive code?

Comment: @IMB updated, should help

Comment: It looks like it's going to work but it doesn't. Tried single and multilines.

Comment: You can make it more complex, write everything in one single file (script) and then `cat my-file.sh | ssh 1.2.3.4` e.g. run the script

Answer (score 0):

For those who care, I figured something out which works for me. A simplified version of the above code is:

```
stage: deploy
script:
  - >
    ssh 1.2.3.4
    "
      docker login -u foo -p bar example.com;
      docker pull my_image;
      docker run -d -p 80:80 my_image;
      and so on ...;
      exit;
    "
```